# How to use paysafe payment solution with ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, payment-gateway

How to use paysafe payment solution  with ruby on rails ?
Is there any gem available for that or I will have to use API or something else. Please let me know best possible solution I should Use.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're asking about implementing [Paysafecard API](http://www.paysafecard.com/uk/business/downloads/downloads/technical-data/api-client/). Then you should look at this [fork of ActiveMerchant](https://github.com/stopdropandrew/active_merchant/blob/96ce94af8c7995249f2025ebf3bc406244c87ee8/lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/paysafe.rb). It may be outdated, but it would be a nice starting point for you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a developer center for CC processing on paysafe.

developer.paysafe.com

On here you can find all of the SDK's. You can find the information that you are looking for below.

https://developer.paysafe.com/en/sdks/server-side/ruby/introduction/

Hope that this helps.